# how to show popup on insertion point on hot key press

Tags: cocoa, caret

I want to know, how apple's dictionary app is showing popup on pressing cmd+ctrl+d on word in any application. Please let me know how I'll achieve the same for my cocoa app.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you get the selection's position with `NSRect insertionRect=[[self layoutManager] boundingRectForGlyphRange:[self selectedRange] inTextContainer:[self textContainer]]` and then create that popup using `insertionRect.origin` as the origin of its frame.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. But, sorry i am not getting how i can call boundingRectForGlyphRange:inTextContainer: for another app like TextEdit within my CGEventRef eventTapFunction(CGEventTapProxy proxy, CGEventType type, CGEventRef event, void *refcon).